# Piping of the regex is it possible?

Tags: regex

In regex is it possible that the result from one regex is an input to another regex.

like for an example in unix/linux when we fire command like:

```
$ls -l | grep "Aug"
```

the result of first `ls` is an input to `grep`.

Comment: What kind of result from the first regex? The match? The line that has a match? A capturing group? Matched text after replacement?

Comment: @nhahtdh it could be any thing.. The match? The line that has a match? A capturing group? Matched text after replacement?

Comment: In different cases, you may have to use different tool to achieve what you want. You can get the match and the line that has the match from grep (with various flags), but capturing group and replacement will need other tool (awk, sed).

Comment: Sure it's possible to pipe the output of 1 grep to another grep. But there doesn't seem to be a good reason to do that.  Because whatever extra filtering would be done by the second grep can probably already be done via the first grep.  What are you really trying to do? Maybe you want to lookup sed or awk or perl.

Comment: I am talking about java / javascript/ php regex.. the command given in question is just for example..

Comment: Wouldn't call it piping in those languages. But you can always use a regex to match and extract information from strings, and then do other stuff with the extracted information. Including other regex matches or replacements.  Syntax will of course depend on the language.

Comment: Maybe you want to do something like using a regex that only matches filenames with a month name in them?  In regex you have an OR.  For example : `/(JAN|FEB)/`  will match JAN or FEB.